# Can't Change property value through a method in a WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, oop, woocommerce

I'm trying to check if WooCommerce is active or not, I created a property with with a default value of false, then I created a method to check if WooCommerce is active using is_plugin_active() and admin_init hook, if active the value of the property must be updated to true: here is the code:

```
class MyClass{

    public $woo_active = false;

    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'check_if_woo_active' ) );
    }

    // check if WooCommerce is active
    public function check_if_woo_active(){

        if( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ){
            $this->woo_active = true;
        }

    }

    // is_woo_active()
    public function is_woo_active(){
        return $this->woo_active;
    }
}
$var = new MyClass();
var_dump( $var->is_woo_active() );
```

the issue is that var_dump returns false even if WooCommerce is active, BUT, if I use var_dump inside the function check_if_woo_active(), it returns true.

Why the property value is not updated? thanks

**Updated:**

The Second Solution as @helgatheviking sugested works fine, also this works very well and short

```
class MyClass{

    // check if WooCommerce is active
    public function is_woo_active(){
        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
        if( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$var = new MyClass();
var_dump( $var->is_woo_active() );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, then `$var = new MyClass();` is run *before* `admin_init` so the `check_if_woo_active()` isn't run.

Couple things you could do. First, I will usually launch my plugin on the `woocommerce_loaded` hook. That way I am 100% sure WooCommerce is running.

```
class MyClass{

    protected static $instance = null;  

     /**
     * Main MyClass Instance
     *
     * Ensures only one instance of MyClass is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @static
     * @see MyClass()
     * @return MyClass - Main instance
     * @since 0.1.0
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) && ! ( self::$instance instanceof MyClass ) ) {
            self::$instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct(){
        // Do what you want, WC is definitely active
    }


}


/**
 * Returns the main instance of class.
 *
 * @return MyClass
 */
function MyClass() {
    return MyClass::instance();
}

// Launch the class if WooCommerce is loaded:
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'MyClass' );
```

You could also mimic what WooCommerce does with their premium plugins and check the option that stores the active plugins:

```
class MyClass{

    private static $active_plugins;

    public static function get_active_plugins() {

        self::$active_plugins = (array) get_option( 'active_plugins', array() );

        if ( is_multisite() ){
            self::$active_plugins = array_merge( self::$active_plugins, get_site_option( 'active_sitewide_plugins', array() ) );
        }
    }

    // check if WooCommerce is active
    public static function check_if_woo_active() {

        if ( ! self::$active_plugins ) self::get_active_plugins();

        return in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', self::$active_plugins ) || array_key_exists( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', self::$active_plugins );
    }

}

var_dump( MyClass::check_if_woo_active() );
```

Comment: Thank you, the second solution is working very well, I found another short way that works without using admin_init and actually there is no need for updating the property value, the method is_woo_active() will do

class MyClass{

 // check if WooCommerce is active
 public function is_woo_active(){
  include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
  if( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ){
   return true;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }
}

$var = new MyClass();
var_dump( $var->is_woo_active() );